# Trying to return all key values of givenName

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to return all key values of givenName but it gets nothing.
I"m new to this is...

```
window.location.href = 'gonative://contacts/getAll?callback=contacts_callback';

function contacts_callback(data) {
    var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
    var obj = JSON.parse(obj);
    var givenName = obj.contacts[0].givenName;

    var keys = Object.keys(obj.contacts.givenName);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = keys;

}
```

Comment: How does `data` looks like?

Comment: The code is never executed, you're redirecting to a new page.

Comment: it's a very large data because this is getting access from the address book of your phone

Comment: If `obj.contacts` is an array, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: yes, it's an array

Comment: don't waste time with that `var obj` stuff - use `function contacts_callback(obj) {` and remove the next two totally redundant lines

Comment: Please don't post your data in comments. Use **edit** to update your post

Comment: There are more contacts and I want to show all givenName names:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `obj.contacts` is an *array* of objects, each having a `givenName` property

Since `obj.contacts` is an array, it is unlikely to have a `givenName` property itself (it could, but then you wouldn't be getting that through JSON)

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj.contacts.givenName);
```

is same as

```
var keys = Object.keys(undefined);
```

and you **should** be getting an error in the browser developer tools console at this point

You'll want to use `Array#map` function as follows

```
function contacts_callback(obj) {
    var givenNames = obj.contacts.map(({givenName}) => givenName);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = givenNames;
}
```

Note

```
function contacts_callback(data) {
    var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
    var obj = JSON.parse(obj);
```

besides the obvious error (doesn't bother javascript though) of declaring the same variable twice (obj), the code is identical to:

```
function contacts_callback(obj) {
```

> Note: however, that if the code inside the function were to mutate any values in `obj`, then, the original code should be used if you do not want to make changes to the passed in object

Comment: @DigiNetEvents - note: please use browser developer tools console for debugging, you would've seen an error

Comment: Calling stringify and parse is a way of making a deep copy of an object. But there's no need to do that in this function.

Comment: @Barmar - I know that, but there's no need in this case - it would be different if the passed in object was being mutated - I've updated the answer with this point